# Monte Carlo domain not-so-dense

Tags: integration, monte-carlo

I [already posted it on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503384/152812), but maybe this is a better place:

I have a 5D integral being calculated with a Monte Carlo uniform random sampling. The issue is that the region of integration is very small and for 100000 points I get only around 20-30 points every time. The function has to be calculated several times for a certain parameter, which doesn't change the integration region but changes only the magnitude of the result (which is good, I suppose).

After several runs, I gathered some hundreds of points which are a valid match for the integration region. I was thinking about using those points to improve the integration result, but how can I do that, in a correct way?

EDIT: on the plane, the boundary is defined by an expression defining some kind of "little line" going from x = y = 150 up diagonally to infinity, so it's a thin domain. it is defined by all the five parameters in the function.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Why is the region of integration so small? What defines its boundaries?

Comment: Maybe he is using rejection sampling. Most of the points are rejected.

Comment: the integration region is very sparse, that's it. As I wrote, out of 10^6 points I get only 35 usable points maximum. I collected all the points found with the various runs, and I want to know how can I use them.

Comment: What's the shape of the integration region? You can't tweak the proposal distribution when moving from one point to the next to the shape of the region of interest.

Comment: Can you give more information about the region of integration? Is that given by some polynomial /bezier lines? As far as I know you are not chained to using a homogeneous random distribution as long as you use appropriate weights. If the integration domain is somehow geometrical in one of the 5 dimensions, you might make use of that by using a different random distribution for your points.

Comment: @MPIchael I described it in the EDIT.

Comment: @LowFieldTheory I feel like this would be pretty easily handled by finding an approximate (and relatively simple) distribution that represents roughly where your points should be located in the domain to contribute to the integral and then using importance sampling. You could also use some good sampling approaches like Markov Chain Monte Carlo or any similar techniques as these tend to use information you get about valid points in your sampling to help you find more.

Comment: The most elegant way, I think, is to go the rigorous route and use some Adaptive Monte Carlo Methods. As far as I can tell, they use a devide-and-conquer approach to selecting where to put the samples. Since you are in 5D, it is not obvious how you may choose a distribution by hand (depending on the int.), so that might be the way to go: (https://www.uzh.ch/cmsssl/physik/dam/jcr:ff1992bc-e15f-4602-9c61-268b8f1d5041/lec3.pdf)

Comment: Additional Link: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration). You are currently using the standard version. If you give the article a good read you should find a method that works for your case (MISER (?)).